# data synchronization from unreliable data source to SQL table

Tags: database, design-patterns, synchronization, datasource, etl

I am looking for pattern, framework or best practice to handle a generic problem of application level data synchronisation.

Let's take an example with only 1 table to make it easier.

- I have an unreliable datasource of product catalog. Data can occasionally be unavailable or incomplete or inconsistent. ( issue might come from manual data entry error, ETL failure...)
- I have a live copy in a Mysql table in use by a live system. Let's say a website.

I need to implement safety mecanism when updating the mysql table to "synchronize" with original data source. Here are the safety criteria and the solution I an suggesting:

- avoid deleting records when they temporarily disappear from datasource => use "deleted" boulean/date column or an archive/history table.
- check for inconsistent changes => configure rules per columns such as : should never change, should only increment,
- check for integrity issue => (standard problem, no point discussing approach)
- ability to rollback last sync=> restore from history table ? use a version inc/date column ?

What I am looking for is best practice and pattern/tool  to handle such problem. If not you are not pointing to THE solution, I would be grateful of any keywords suggestion that would me narrow down which field of expertise to explore.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem importing data from web analytics providers - they suffer the same problems as your catalog. This is what we did:

- Every import/sync is assigned a unique id (auto_increment int64)
- Every table has a history table that is identical to the original, but has an additional column "superseded_id" which gets the import-id of the import, that changed the row (deletion is a change) and the primary key is (row_id,superseded_id)
- Every UPDATE copies the row to the history table before changing it
- Every DELETE moves the row to the history table

This makes rollback very easy:

- Find out the import_id of the bad import
- `REPLACE INTO main_table SELECT <everything but superseded_id> FROM history table WHERE superseded_id=<bad import id>`
- `DELETE FROM history_table WHERE superseded_id>=<bad import id>`

For databases, where performance is a problem, we do this in a secondary database on a different server, then copy the found-to-be-good main table to the production database into a new table `main_table_$id` with $id being the highest import id and have main_table be a trivial view to `SELECT * FROM main_table_$someid`. Now by redefining the view to `SELECT * FROM main_table_$newid` we can atomically swicth the table.

Comment: totally agree with that approach for rollback issue.

Comment: do you have any issue with data integrity in some  records ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "data integrity" - corrupt rows (e.g. bad dates, negative numbers, ...) are filtered out before doing the update/insert (in some cases we will reject the complete import). If you mean e.g. a constraint violated, this happens quite often. We then reject the complete import.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for your feedback. I am trying to establish best practice and find or build a framework that could support rapid and robust implementation of such problem.

Comment: @Eugene thanks for your feedback. You got it right integrity was referring to filtering out corrupt rows. Actually there is two stages:
1- checking invalid records. Some will cause record skip , some will cause withdrawing the whole process.
2- checking invalid update. When modification to the database are not consistent with previous value.

Comment: I am trying to establish best practice and find or build a framework that could support rapid and robust implementation of such problem and extend to multiple tables.
But I am stuck by the lack of keywords to find relevant paper, blogs or tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a single solution to all this - probably because each project is so different. However, here are two techniques I've used in the past:

**Embed the concept of version and validity into your data model**

This is a way to deal with change over time without having to resort to history tables; it does complicate your queries, so you should use it sparingly.

For instance, instead of having a product table as follows

```
PRODUCTS
Product_ID primary key
Price
Description
AvailableFlag
```

In this model, if you want to delete a product, you execute `"delete from product where product_id = ..."`; modifying price would be `"update products set price = 1 where product_id = ...."`

With the versioned model, you have:

```
PRODUCTS
product_ID primary key
valid_from datetime
valid_until datetime
deleted_flag
Price
Description
AvailableFlag
```

In this model, deleting a product requires you to `update products set valid_until = getdate() where product_id = xxx and valid_until is null`, and then insert a new row with the "deleted_flag = true".

Changing price works the same way.

This means that you can run queries against your "dirty" data and insert it into this table without worrying about deleting items that were accidentally missed off the import. It also allows you to see the evolution of the record over time, and roll-back easily.

**Use a ledger-like mechanism for cumulative values**

Where you have things like "number of products in stock", it helps to create transactions to modify the amount, rather than take the current amount from your data feed.

For instance, instead of having a `amount_in_stock` column on your products table, have a "product_stock_transaction" table:

```
product_stock_transactions 
product_id FK        transaction_date     transaction_quantity transaction_source
1                    1 Jan 2012             100                 product_feed
1                    2 Jan 2012              -3                 stock_adjust_feed
1                    3 Jan 2012              10                 product_feed
```

On 2 Jan, the quantity in stock was 97; on 3 Jan, 107.

This design allows you to keep track of adjustments and their source, and is easier to manage when moving data from multiple sources.

Both approaches can create large amounts of data - depending on the number of imports and the amount of data - and can lead to complex queries to retrieve relatively simple data sets.

It's hard to plan for performance concerns up front - I've seen both "history" and "ledger" work with large amounts of data. However, as Eugen says in his comment below, if you get to an excessively large ledger, it may be necessary to to clean up the ledger table by summarizing the current levels, and deleting (or archiving) old records.

Comment: I am sorry but this approach only works with reliable datasource.
What I am trying to address is quite the opposite. When I recieve incorrect/corrupted data, I want to minimize the risk of contagion/corruption to main database. Especially the ledger like mechanism would make sure that 1 single incorrect import will corrupt the total amount value forever.

Comment: Sorry to -1 this, but I have seen too many ledger-like systems that work fine at the start, but choke after a month when every request for a quantity in stock necessitates adding up 1.000.000 rows

Comment: yes, there's no way to avoid corrupting your data if you accept bad data into the database in the first place. However, assuming you have some way to validate the data in the first place, the ledger allows you to track obvious anomalies - ooh, we wiped out the entire stock record on 1/1/2012 - and correct it by creating an additional transaction. This at least gives you built-in audit and history.

Comment: @Eugen, yes, there can be performance problems - but I've seen this work quite happily for systems with very large amounts of data. I have updated the answer to reflect your concern though.